# Facebook Payment Graph API does not return user data for a payment using local currencies

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment

I'm in the process of updating a facebook application to use local currency payments, following the [How-to: Local Currency Payments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/payments/) tutorial as a guide.

Its almost fully functional but I'm hitting a wall with the final step - when I retrieve details of the payment the response consistently returns null for the user property.

To retrieve payment details I'm requesting an APP_ACCESS_TOKEN and calling:

```
graph.facebook.com/PAYMENT_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Response (snippet):

```
{
    "id":"34567890",
    "user":null,
    "application":{
        "id":"12345",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Obviously, without that user data I'm unable to take any further action. Debugging info:

- My app is not running in sandbox mode
- It does not require any specific user permissions
- I've tested with both payment testers, and real card payments (same result)
- In my 'realtime updates' subscription I've included *actions* and *disputes* as fields (these appear to be the only two available options).
- If I hit the graph for a history of all payments for that user I can see the payment in the list.

I'm out of ideas and cannot find any additional pointers in the documentation to assist me in this. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Comment: Could you post the Payment_id?